# Can AWS RDS be used as a MySQL host only?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

Is it possible to use AWS' RDS MySQL solution in tandem with my current file server host? By that, I mean, can I connect to the RDS MySQL server as I am with my hosts current database?

I've tried the AWS documentation but it seems a bit flaky in this area.

Thank you,

Comment: Can you add a little more detail

Comment: For instance, some hosts don't allow a redirect out. That is part of their racket, get you to want a service upgrade like VPS

Comment: Amazon AWS has flexible accèss restrictions, so the short answer is *maybe*. You'll want to check that performance from your existing host to the RDS instance is acceptable, mind you. Data transfer between different geographic locations can be wildly unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon RDS is a database server, just like any other. If you start up an RDS MySQL server, you can connect to it from anything else that can connect to a MySQL server.

The difference is that you do not have direct host access to the RDS server. Meaning, you cannot SSH into it and get a command prompt.

But you can connect to it from any MySQL client, including MySQL Workbench.